# Проблема с массивами php

Tags: массивы, php

Всем привет. Есть у меня вот такой вот код:

```
$textareaValue = 'aaa@aaa|aaa/nbbb@bbb|bbb/nggg@ggg|ggg';
$smth = explode('/n',$textareaValue);
oreach ($smth as $aa => $bb) {
list($emails, $passwords) = explode('|', $bb);
foreach ($emails as $a1 => $b1) {
    echo $b1.':';
}
foreach ($passwords as $a2 => $b2) {
     echo $b2.'<br>';
     } 
}
```

Код делит сначала строку на строки вида "aaa@aaa|aaa" и добавляет их в массив, а затем каждую строку в массиве делит на еще на две части. Но они записываются в два разных массива.
А с ключами в них творится вообще непонятно что.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объединить их после деления в один массив вида `$key => $item`, где `$key` будет равен "aaa@aaa" (Пример), а `$item` будет равен "aaa" (Пример)? Или хотя бы как сделать так, чтобы ключи в массивах после деления шли от 0 и до n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$textareaValue = 'aaa@aaa|aaa/nbbb@bbb|bbb/nggg@ggg|ggg';
$rows = explode('/n',$textareaValue);
$result = array();
foreach( $rows AS $key) {
    list($email, $pwd) = explode( '|', $key);
    $result[ $email] = $pwd;
}
print_r( $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Как вариант](http://ideone.com/E0mHjd):

```
$str = 'aaa@aaa|aaa/nbbb@bbb|bbb/nggg@ggg|ggg';
parse_str(preg_replace(array('/\//', '/\|/'), array('&', '='), $str), $res);
print_r($res);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [aaa@aaa] => aaa
    [nbbb@bbb] => bbb
    [nggg@ggg] => ggg
)
```

Comment: красиво! Но что, если в пароле окажется "&" или "="?

Comment: @Sergiks, ясное дело, что тогда такой вариант не прокатит )) Он только под конкретные условия задачи.